# Can i use a higher number version of compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion than it's used in my version of React Native?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm on react-native@0.61.1 and in my project, the file "android/build.gradle" have those two variables (compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion) targeting android api 28. But android 10 has been released with api 29 now.
When we upgrade to a newer version of react native, sometimes we have to modify those versions.
Can we modify it before they release a newer version or react native with api 29 ?

Comment: Yes but if you third party dependencies first you have to check whether they are compatible with it,

Comment: I was thinking that as newer android API are not breaking, i thought that it would be easy to update the version from 28 to 29 but it brings me lots of compiling java errors.. Even if i revert the version et gradlew clean the build it continues to show same errors.. i have to completely delete my android folder to make it compile again in release.